# List of objects based on user relationships

Tags: python, django

So I've got a model, Post, which is related to a User. Users can have connections (basically just friends). I would like to get a list of all posts made by a user's connections. I've already got something that works, but this is getting into territory that is unfamiliar to me, and I'd be very appreciative of any advice anyone can give me in terms of performance and best practices. Here is what I have so far:

```
    connections = self.request.user.connections.all()
    id_list = []
    for connection in connections:
        id_list.append(connection.to_user.id)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=id_list)
```

Any help is much appreciated. I'm sure there're more Django-y ways of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use a queryset with the `in` lookup. This will translate your lookup directly into a database query. So, the overhead of the for loop is saved.

```
connections = self.request.user.connections.all()
posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=connections)
```

Also, this is a *django-y* way :)

Answer (score 1):

Simpler:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(user__in=self.request.user.connections.all())
```